# How to design an amplifier for a sensing liquid level using capacitive probes?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, sensor, dielectric

In this problem I have a capacitor that is submerged in a varying level of dielectric fluid. Therefore, the capacitance varies linearly with the height of the fluid. How should I design a simple op amp circuit to achieve this? I believe it should be a non-inverting amplifier circuit.

[image]

[image]

My circuit:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is hard to do if you can start with an AC signal rather than DC. But making the signal frequency vary in response to the changing capacitance, instead of the amplitude, might be easier and more accurate.

Comment: Are you trying to measure the capacitance or do you really want a gain controlled by the capacitance?

Comment: Hi copper.hat, I want a gain that is controlled by capacitance.

Comment: I was doing a lot of trial and error and still couldn’t really find a good circuit design. I find it impossible to do with dc so it should be done with ac I guess

Comment: Try to use a "charge amplifier" (an inverting amplifier with C1 and C2 instead R1 and R2). C2 is your capacitor (sensor). Drive the circuit by an AC sine signal and take the AC output voltage.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem ("I want a gain that is controlled by capacitance") - what are you trying to achieve? Gain requires an input signal - where is your input signal?

Comment: *I want a gain that is controlled by capacitance.* Explain **WHY** that is needed.

Comment: *I find it impossible to do with dc so it should be done with ac I guess* Not a good reason, explain **why** DC is an issue (perhaps the liquid is conductive). Stating: I cannot use DC so I must use AC (without explaining why DC doesn't work) is really bad engineering. Also changing the gain of an opamp isn't a commonly used solution to measure capacitance. Stop thinking in a solution you made up, instead, provide more details of what you want to achieve (voltage that depends on a level of a liquid) without saying **how** that must be done.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, so let me clarify the problem again. Firstly, I have a capacitor that is has varying capacitance based on the height of fluid. Now, the question wants the height of fluid as a parameter that changes the gain (proportionately). It does not provide me with an input signal so I guess it could be any. I have just uploaded the circuit that Ive come up with, feel free to correct me.

Comment: The question **does not** require changing of gain. It requires fixed gain so that the output is proportional to the input.

Comment: yes, at any particular height of the liquid, the capacitance is constant and so is the gain. But I don't know how the circuit should look like.

Comment: If you understand that the gain is constant then please fix the question title. You are asking for "variable amplification" which suggests variable gain. Your comment (third up from here) is also asking for "changes the gain".

Comment: Can we assume that the "sensing electronics" really sees an "ideal" capacitor? I am afraid there will be a parallel resistor ? In this case, the problem (and the circuitry) is more complicated.

Comment: I think the question is poorly phrases. I could interpret it as "(d) the output should be a sinusoid with amplitude proportional to the liquid level" since no input was drawn. For full marks you'd have to include the oscillator, and then filter it with with single pole RC, using the C from the plates/liquid.

Comment: Your title edit is still not correct. "*... that has **fixed gain** based on a capacitor? The **gain should be proportional** to the capacitance*". The two bold parts contradict each other. You want "How to design an amplifier for a sensing liquid level using capacitive probes". Forget about mentioning gain.

Comment: Alright noted, thanks!

Comment: Yuan Qi. Are you allowed to use three opamps? I have a circuit consisting of a GIC and a summing block with a voltage input (sinewave) and a voltage output (opamp output node) which is linearly prop. to a grounded capacitor.

Comment: The question says "an op amp", so I guess only one is allowed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think put the capacitor as a degeneration as in the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVwUjl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, A and B are the input nodes of your sensing element as you show in the figure. \$vo_+\$ and \$vo_-\$ are the differential outputs.
For frequencies below (\$\frac{g_m}{C}\$), the gain of the circuit is proportional to the capacitance.
$$A_v = \frac{R}{\frac{1}{\omega 2C}} = 2\omega RC$$

Based on this gain capacitance can be calculated.

**EDIT**
The above circuit is not an opAmp circuit. But as LvW said, you can use differentiator with OpAmp to get the gain proportional to capacitor:
$$A_v = \omega CR$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIjJSn.png)</sup>

Comment: Hi, can you explain what M1 and M2 are? I have never seen them before.

Comment: Hi, M1 and M2 are (Metal Oxide Semiconductor) MOS transistors. Internally the OpAmp is made from these transistors.

Comment: Does that mean that I can treat the dotted box as an op amp? Is it possible for you to simplify the circuit for me? thanks !

Comment: Please check edits

Comment: I see, thanks !, is this a differentiator circuit?

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1VhaC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit diagram shows a positive integrator (DEBOO Integrator, NIC- intergrator). It has the advantage that the integrating capacitor is grounded (which may be important for the discussed application).

For R2=R4 and R1=R3 the opamps output voltage is **Vout=Vin(2/jwT)** with **T=R1*C.**

Therefore, the output voltage is inversely proportional to the capacitance of C and has - within certain limits, depending on the used opamp - a fixed phase shift of -90 deg (against Vin) .

If it is required that the output voltage is directly proportional to the capacitance you need another opamp with a feedback loop consisting of this integrator. However, in this case, specific stability considerations are to be taken.

EDIT: The working principle of the shown circuit is based on an IDEAL capacitor (resistive loses neglectable).

Comment: Hi, is there any way to do the same thing with a simpler circuit? This is because this is my first circuit course in university and I don't think the question will be that complicated... Anyway, I still appreciate your time.

Comment: With an Integrator in the feedback loop, the whole sysytem is "differentating" . Therefore, from the beginning you could try to use a differentiator (stabilized). However, the capacitor will not be grounded.